# HANA Stored Procedure as Model Input Paramter

Tags: stored-procedures, hana, hana-sql-script

I have a requirement to create an Input Parameter for my Calculation View that defaults to the most recent `Post_Date`.

I am using "Derived from Procedure/Scalar Function" as my Input Type.

My Stored Procedure looks up the Max `Post_Date` but I am having trouble mapping the OUT Variable from the SP, to the Model Input Parameter.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE "SCHEMA"."SP_TEST"
(OUT IP_TO_DATE VARCHAR(8))
    LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
    DEFAULT SCHEMA TEST 
    READS SQL DATA AS 
BEGIN 
SELECT MAX (POST_DATE1) INTO IP_TO_DATE FROM "SCHEMA"."TABLE";
END;

CALL "SCHEMA"."SP_TEST"(?)
```

Has anyone worked with Stored Procedures as Input Parameters?!

Per the HANA Modeling Guide, it seems I can do this?
[Create Input Parameters](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_HANA_PLATFORM/57a523b496cc4531a3676f5d94644899/a172fa29c63e4881832530e24c9ed10a.html)

Comment: What sort of trouble do you have? can you be more specific?

Comment: Hi Lars.  My SP works and provides the output as expected when Called. 
The problem is when Previewing my model, I am expecting the input parameter to default to this value generated from the SP and it is not. A comment from Florian on SCN says he believes it to be a missing update though I am not positive. I am using HANA 1.00.102.05.1455873859 with HANA Studio 2.1.20